# webpack less-loader not working

Tags: reactjs, less, webpack

I am trying to build my react-redux project using webpack. I have the following line to handle the less files:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/, 
    include: /(stylesheets)/, 
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader?sourceMap') 
}
```

For some reason I am getting the following error message:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: C:\path\to\project\client\stylesheets\app.less Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

*I am running on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

as per the 'less-loader' [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader), your webpack should like below...

Amend your webpack config file accordingly...

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    // must be 'source-map' or 'inline-source-map'
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    // activate source maps via loader query
                    'css?sourceMap!' +
                    'less?sourceMap'
                )
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract inline css into separate 'styles.css'
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the include path, since the script runs on Windows. A full path needs to be given in the include field:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/, 
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'stylesheets'), 
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader?sourceMap') 
}
```